# windows mobile 6.5 vs 6.0 datagrid not working

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, compact-framework

when data is displayed on a Windows Mobile 6.0 or 5.0 device, the datagrid columns width can be controlled and look fine.
However when running on a Windows Mobile 6.5 device, there is no control of the columns width.
the columns are all the same size and data in the columns are cut off.

Has anyone seen this behavior and if so, how did you correct.

Program is written vb.net in VS2005.

thank you
Ron Berardinis

Comment: Show us code for a simple repro example